# How to populate cell based on dropdown date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I couldn't find this anywhere so I have to ask:

I want to have a Dropdown with all the dates and when I select one date, 
I can enter a couple of values in different cells for that one date. 
These should be saved so that I can come back and look at the values 
from different dates.

I'm using [Excel 365 ProPlus] if this is of any importance.

Could you please redirect me to a website/tutorial or let me know how 
this can be achieved?

**FUTHER EXPLANATION
You have cell "A1" which contains multiple dates in a dropdown fashion:
[01.02.2018]
[02.02.2018]

Now when you select [01.02.2018], cell "B1" should display "some text". 
Else, if you select [02.02.2018], cell "B1" should display "some other text".
**

Thank you.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking.  If you create a dropdown list and then select from it, it sticks your selection in the cell.  Then you just enter what you want in the adjacent cells.  The dropdown affects just that cell, it doesn't perform any kind of linking to other cells.  Can you be more explicit about the problem?

Comment: You have 1 cell which contains multiple dates in a dropdown fashion:
[01.02.2018]
[02.02.2018]

Now when you select [01.02.2018], the cell next to it will display [lorem]. 
Else, if you select [02.02.2018], the cell next to it will display [ipsum].

Comment: You have cell "A1" which contains multiple dates in a dropdown fashion:
[01.02.2018]
[02.02.2018]

Now when you select [01.02.2018], cell "B1" should display "some text". 
Else, if you select [02.02.2018], cell "B1" should display "some other text".

Comment: Excel works in reverse of that.  The value in one cell doesn't push the content of another cell, it just affects itself.  If you want B1 to be dependent on what value is in A1, then B1 needs to test A1 to see what's there, and then display an appropriate value.  An IF test in B1 is a common way to do that.  It depends on the number of choices and associated values you need to deal with.  If it is a big list, you might need to lookup the associated value in a table, or choose from a list.  We would need more detail for an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a lookup scenario. In a different sheet or in a different range on the same sheet, there is a table with dates in the first column and text like "lorem" or "ipsum" in the next column.

When you select a date in A1, B1 uses a formula to look up the corresponding text from the table.

This concept can be used in scenarios like invoices, where the user selects the product code from a drop-down and the product description and the product price are then looked up with a formula.

There are heaps of resources on the web for Excel lookup formulas. The most popular formula is Vlookup, where the lookup value must be in the first column of the lookup table.

[image]

Another, more powerful and more flexible option is the Index/Match combo, where the lookup value can be any column in the lookup table.

Comment: @BogdanLazar, note the VLOOKUP() formula in teylyn's screenshot is in cell B2, so it specifies the value displayed in B2.  It looks up the value in cell $A2 (Ap2) in the lookup table $H$3:$J$8, and returns the value in column 2 of that table (GrannySmith).  See these links for more information on how to use [VLOOKUP()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) and [INDEX/MATCH](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact).